# can't get the parent div class list with e.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I seem to know what the problem is but i can't solve it, so here's my code

```
<div className="reason" onClick={openTab}>
      <div className="reason-title">
            <div className="icon" >
                 <i className="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <span>title</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

and the java script that i wrote

```
const openTab = (e) => {
      if (e.target.classList.contains("active")) {
          e.target.classList.remove("active")
      } else {
          e.target.classList.add("active")

      }
}
```

so the problem is whenever i click on the parent div wherever the child `divs` haven't occupied it's ok, but for example when ever i click on the title, it checks the `classList` of that element, while i just want to check the parent div, in this case the reason div.
and i don't wanna use `jquery` but i can't seem to solve it with pure `javascript`.

Comment: You probably need `event.currentTarget` or `event.parentNode`, are you using react?

Comment: thanks man, that worked. and yeah, i'm using react, is there a better way to this on react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need `event.currentTarget` or `event.parentNode`:

```
e.currentTarget.classList.contains("active")
```

In React it's better to not directly modify the DOM, you should use the React "way", like:

```
const openTab = (e) => {
  active = active ? false : true
}

className={active ? 'active' : ''}
```